# Subclass UITabBarController in iOS6 with storyboards

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I started a new project with iOS 6 ARC and Storyboards

I made a very simple app that has a Tabbar and 2 views

[image]

so now I created a TestViewController file with is extending UITabBarController and I put the custom class in the storyboard.

now the issue is that I am trying to implement some delegate methods like

```
- (BOOL) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

But it never calls it. Can anyone help?

I noticed too that if I put that code in the first view controller it works fine. It seems like the first view controller overwrites the TabBarController before. I am very confused.

for more testing I added in the TestViewController.m some logging:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad { 
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
   NSLog(@"%@",self.tabBarController.viewControllers);
}
```

and the view controllers are null.

I even tried doing `self.tabBarController.delegate = self;`

But still no solution.

Comment: ok so i tried some more: when i add `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers;` to my `TestViewController.h` file i can access the view 2 view controllers! which is good... now when i go to the first view controller and get the tabBarController property and set the delegate to `self` then everything works... so why is the tabbarcontroller in the file i have not right away the tabbarcontroller that is later used???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestViewController is your tab bar controller, so your log should just be self.viewControllers, not self.tabBarController.viewControllers. You shouldn't need to add the property viewControllers either, since your subclass inherits that property from UITabBarController. The reason your delegate message is not called is because of the same problem. You should set the delegate with (in TestViewController):

```
self.delegate = self;
```

This is assuming that you want TestViewController to be the delegate, it wasn't clear to me if that's what you wanted.

Comment: ahh that makes soooo much sense :) sometimes it can be so simple... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried linking them in Interface Builder?
Add this to your header file first though
`@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;`

Comment: I cant link them in IB. Just doesn't let me. If I just add it to the file its just empty.

Comment: Did you add it in your appDelegate?

Comment: no... in the TestViewController class. why would i need it in the appdelegate?